# Line through two points of parallelepiped

Tags: geometry, vectors, analytic-geometry

Given the parallelepiped

[image]

I need to find the equation of the line through the points $A$ and $F$. I know the line which contains $DG$ has equation given by

$$X=t(1,2,-3),\quad t\in\mathbb{R}$$

and $F(0,2,0)$. My question is: may I say the equation I need to find is given by

$$X=(0,2,0)+\lambda(1,2,-3),\quad\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$$
since the vectors $AF$ and $DG$ are parallels?

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Comment: Yes that's correct, as a minor issue maybe you should use another name for this line.

Comment: @user I didn't get it. What do you mean?

Comment: @mvfs314 It is just a detail, since the line which contains DG is named X,maybe the other one can be named Y, for example.